# Azure File Storage access by Azure Function

Tags: azure, networking, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

Azure File Storage and Azure Function are under the same subscription.

File Storage has limited access to just:

```
"Enabled from selected virtual networks and IP addresses"
```

and I have a Function which doesn't have static IP address (even the IP addresses that it supposed to use are not correct).

Is there a way to enable access to this File Storage by my function from any IP address?

In the worst case scenario, is there a range for all Azure Function IP addresses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can lock down your storage account when you have your Function App VNet-integrated. This requires your Function to be deployed in either a Dedicated AppServicePlan or as a Premium Function plan. There is a detailed tutorial about this here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-vnet#lock-down-your-storage-account